# first res.send variable works, but the rest dont

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, conditional-statements, http-get

Trying to get the res.send messages to correlate with the SQL query but only the first 'messageToUser' variable (which is just a normal string) works.

```js
app.get('/info', function(req,res) {
       var option1 = req.query.option1
       var option2 = req.query.option2
       var option3 = req.query.option3

       if (option1 == 'SELECT' || option2 == 'SELECT' || option3 == 'SELECT') {
           var messageToUser = 'Please fill out the required fields and try again.';
           console.log('Not all fields were filled out');
       }
       else {
          if (option3 == 'Cash') {
            var queryCash = connection.query('SELECT toll FROM tollschedule.cashtollschedule WHERE interchangeEnter=' + option1 + ' AND interchangeExit=' + option2);
            var formatCash = queryCash[0].toll;
            var answerCash = '$' + parseFloat(formatCash).toFixed(2);
            var messageToUser = 'The toll from ' + option1 + ' to ' + option2 + ' paying with ' + option3 + ' will cost ' + answerCash;
            console.log(queryCash);
            console.log('Toll request received from ' + option1 + ' to ' + option2 + ' costing ' + answerCash);
           }
           else if (option3 == 'E-ZPass') {
             var queryEz = connection.query('SELECT toll FROM tollschedule.ezpasstollschedule WHERE interchangeEnter=' + option1 + ' AND interchangeExit=' + option2);
             var formatEz = queryEz[0].toll;
             var answerEz = '$' + parseFloat(formatEz).toFixed(2);   
             console.log(queryEz);
             console.log('Toll request received from ' + option1 + ' to ' + option2 + ' costing ' + answerEz);
          }
        }
    res.send(messageToUser);
        })
```

Comment: It's not possible for us to debug this. We don't know what your `req` parameter even looks like.

Comment: where did you tried to res.send a the second time ?

Comment: I rather doubt this is correct `var queryCash = connection.query(...)` as the query should be asynchronous and either need a callback or `await` (if it's a promise interface).